# Cannot find list of descendants using Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Where are Rake tasks such as `:environment` defined? Is there something lighter than `:environment` which could give me access to the ActiveRecord subclasses, from a Rake task?

I am trying to get a list of models, in a Rake task. This is what I have:

```
namespace :mine do
    namespace :ar do
        desc "my custom"
        task :show_sub => [:environment] do
            puts "Total:#{ActiveRecord::Base.descendants}"
            ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |cls|
                puts cls
            end
        end
    end
end
```

However, all I ever get is `[]`, though I have 3 models defined.

EDIT: I am using Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

The most lightweight way I can imagine to accomplish this is to write the rake task that iterates through all `.rb` files in the current directory, and sub-directories inside your project (in case you have them stashed somewhere weird), and simply outputs the number of files containing the string `< ActiveRecord::Base` (spaces being optional, of course).

One regex pattern that matches this is:

`^class\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s?<\s?ActiveRecord::Base`

...so it only matches lines that include an explicit class declaration, that don't start with a hash `#` mark (i.e. so it's not a comment)

Comment: True, it's a fast results approach, but as soon as you have a comment like `< ActiveRecord::Base` you can go wrong. I know, it's not a big chance of something like this existing in code, but I want `results guaranteed` :).

Comment: Okay, but then you just need to refine the pattern a bit (which I've done) to not match lines that have ActiveRecord::Base behind a hash mark (which indicates a comment). Regex is easily powerful enough to solve this problem, and is going to be much faster than trying to pare down the environment to only get `ActiveRecord` and whatever its dependencies are.